# Google RealTime dB and Firestore in the same Apps

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

we have Android and Web apps that are both using the same Firebase data base, and now we want to add functionality to them both so we have a single chat experience across both. All the chat SDK’s out there and google examples are based on using real time data base as back-end.
Question is can we combine both real time data base and firebase dB in the same App, and what should we look out for? We’re aware that we will need 2 separate projects created.
Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you can use both. No, you don't need separate projects.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the answer- Apprecaited All the SDK’s i’ve Found and the google examples show how to use the RTDB only - Do you know of any that allow us me to use the Firestore/Firestone DB across both the web app and Android?  We wanted to use http://chatsdk.co/. But it only supports the RTDB so it seems ... Any idea if there is an alternative SDK  anyone?

Comment: You're asking for reference to offsite resources.  That's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you're running into a specific problem with the Firebase SDKs, please post here again with those details.

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). Beside that, you can also implement Firebase realtime database functionalities along with Cloud Firestore.